# How do I restart the level in Puzzle'n Desu?

Tags: puzzlen-desu

In the SNES game *Puzzle'n Desu!*, if you make a mistake, what button combination do you need to press?

Comment: Regarding the tags - please see the meta post, [Platform Tags are Useless](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4638/4797).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to hold <kbd>L</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd> at the same time.